# How to generate multiple solutions in task constructor in Moveit2?

Tags: ros2, pick-and-place, moveit2

I am currently doing the pick and place tutorial in the moveit2 tutorials. I am using my own custom model. In the finished tutorial, task constructor generates multiple solutions for most of the stages. However, in my project it only generates single solution as you can see from the [image: image.] How can I increase the number of solution it generates? The stages I used are :

```
 {
    auto stage_open_hand =
        std::make_unique<mtc::stages::MoveTo>("open arm", sampling_planner);
    stage_open_hand->setGroup(arm_group_name);
    stage_open_hand->setGoal("start");    
    task.add(std::move(stage_open_hand));
  }
  auto const target_pose = [] {
    geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped msg;
    msg.header.frame_id = "base_link";
    msg.pose.position.x = 0.3;
    msg.pose.position.y = 0.5;
    msg.pose.position.z = 0.5;
    return msg;
  }();

  {
    auto stage_go_to =
        std::make_unique<mtc::stages::MoveTo>("go to", cartesian_planner);
    stage_go_to->setGroup(arm_group_name);
    stage_go_to->setGoal(target_pose);    
    stage_go_to->setTimeout(2.0);
    stage_go_to->setIKFrame("Motor7Gv_1");
    task.add(std::move(stage_go_to));
  }
```